# Compilation Error - The compiler failed with error code 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I've been having issues deploying to our shared host recently. When deploying via Web Deploy from Visual Studio, 99% of the time I get this error on either the login page or the homepage after logging in. Sometimes I might get a couple of clicks into different sections then it will hit. It usually disappears after a couple of minutes through to maybe 90 minutes.

Webhost running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, IIS8, .NET 4.5.

The webhost has suggested I need to use the x86 build configuration from Visual Studio. I've tried a number of different configurations for Debug / Release in Any Cpu, x86, x64 and all yield the same result.

We've now tried three different servers at the host and I can successfully reproduce the error after publishing basically every time. We just tried a brand new environment and after three deploys, bam 'The compiler failed with error code 1'.

They've pushed back and says it's not their problem, no other clients are affected and it must be something to do with my configuration or settings. I've deployed the same site to my local IIS during development for the last year and never seen the problem. I even started an Azure account today and changed and deployed my site 20 times and couldn't replicate. Further to this, I created a brand new project in VS, made no changes and deployed to the host and managed to trip the exact same error in a completely vanilla / standard VS web project.

I don't know where to go from here - we've invested a lot with this host in terms of paying up front and now they are completely stone walling us on this issue.

Here's the error I get at runtime in the browser;

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv>
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library
>   /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\App_global.asax.0fxbfjfx.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\592e2a3b\29b1fed4_a9a7d001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\566cae42\db53a6d1_a9a7d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\21e1b328\b7f2d4d1_a9a7d001\Elmah.Mvc.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\a19ebce4\b3bb1b1a_4bb0d001\AuthProviders.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\14784cab\ac3152d1_a9a7d001\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\6c4b1e36\af6893f2_24b0d001\Antlr3.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\55a46179\d9526fd2_a9a7d001\Hangfire.SqlServer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\98ce0055\5bcefc1a_4bb0d001\ResearchAdmin.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\bd297971\a10a43d2_a9a7d001\EntityFramework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\409fa562\f13f12d3_a9a7d001\System.Web.Mvc.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\fbaa1837\26a344d3_a9a7d001\System.Web.Helpers.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\963201db\699517d5_a9a7d001\Owin.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\099eba28\818699d5_a9a7d001\StructureMap.Net4.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\7dc6fd96\007f4b16_be7cce01\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\5b5c7757\1d9b01d3_a9a7d001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\036a8b7a\d72127d1_a9a7d001\DDay.iCal.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\cbef3179\f9acd5f3_24b0d001\System.Web.Optimization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\abc23773\e9e056d4_a9a7d001\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\dd2023f8\097a25d5_a9a7d001\Postal.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\ae279640\e33e65d2_a9a7d001\Hangfire.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\2891a974\ff0961d3_a9a7d001\WebMatrix.WebData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\d3e20003\2b39f7d2_a9a7d001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\47d1ca6b\05e37ed4_a9a7d001\Microsoft.Owin.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\a09629f2\d1be4ad3_a9a7d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\41ee05b3\b8e332d1_a9a7d001\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\c4b2bc24\b20645d2_a9a7d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\af441148\1a1547d3_a9a7d001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\45fcd364\26f073d1_a9a7d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\9489863a\4d62a9d1_a9a7d001\Mono.Math.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\51030571\a80fabd1_a9a7d001\Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\2ffb59b1\f28421d3_a9a7d001\System.Web.Razor.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\224a3832\a10539d5_a9a7d001\RazorEngine.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\c5bf8794\519dacd5_a9a7d001\WebActivatorEx.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\e20826ff\441149d3_a9a7d001\System.Web.WebPages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\2f66de0b\ed3255d4_a9a7d001\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\606d1e4b\3bd978d5_a9a7d001\RestSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\b6635993\e5678bd4_a9a7d001\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\2252966f\d059441a_4bb0d001\AuthProviders.EF.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\420b90fc\c16062d1_a9a7d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\a4d97c70\53fbbfd1_a9a7d001\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\7a7ef0a7\bc13ced1_a9a7d001\Elmah.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\1d666353\4f3899d5_a9a7d001\StructureMap.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\4132b786\56e455d3_a9a7d001\WebMatrix.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\assembly\dl3\8eaf4a45\6877f1f3_24b0d001\WebGrease.dll"
>   /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\App_Web_indexvendor.cshtml.a8d08dba.w0o4an61.dll"
>   /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618
>   /warnaserror- 
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\App_Web_indexvendor.cshtml.a8d08dba.w0o4an61.0.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b101b654\d371881d\App_Web_indexvendor.cshtml.a8d08dba.w0o4an61.1.cs"

At the same time ELMAH is recording an error along these lines and I believe the two are related;

> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): External component has
>   thrown an exception.    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: are you sure your web application is targeting the same version as your hosting environment? maybe they do not support the version you are targeting. check for versions 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6

Comment: Make sure also that the dll's that you are referencing from the GAC on your development environment are also GAC in the target environment

Comment: Unlikely it helps, but on your place i would try to delete all unnecessary dlls from project.

Comment: @dotctor - I thought the same. The server is running 4.5.2 and my app is targeting the same.

Comment: Try targeting a lower version like 4.5 and deploy and test if the problem persist.@Tom

Comment: Thanks @dotctor - I have tried both 4.5.2 and 4.5 now. Should I try straight up 4.0?!

Comment: Give it a try, I had this problem with my hosting environment which support .NET 4.5 and I was pointing my application to 4.5.1.

Comment: @dotctor - I went down to 4.0 and the problem continues.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but probably not the same, because in my case the error didn't disappear after waiting some time. But maybe it is a hint where the problem may come from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316738/compilation-error-the-compiler-failed-with-error-code-1-asp-net-error-after/33316754#33316754

Answer (score 4):

Recycling and then stop & start application pool saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

I also get the same error when I am deploying my changes in the application under IIS. After refreshing the application pool this hasn't got solved. I also delete the temporary files under .Netframework. This got solved only by rebooting the server.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem while debugging in Visual Studio using IISExpress.

Resolved it by exiting Visual Studio and reopening.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one but if your website is working on your local server and you publish it successfully but it crashes with this error, before changing any parameter, make sure to clean the project before publishing. Should do it anyway but took me a long time to realise that this was the issue.