# Compilation Error - The compiler failed with error code 1 - asp.net error after publishing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnet-compiler

After publishing my asp.net MVC 5 website to the hosting environment, I got the following error message

```
Compilation Error - The compiler failed with error code 1
```

Nothing else besides the compiler-call itself is shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, the MVC-templates added the following section in the `web.config` file:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

After removing them, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks it resolved my issue as well, I was getting The compiler failed with error code -532462766. but can you or anyone explain why it was happening

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the server , solved the issue for me.

Comment: Life saving tip!I had a meeting for a demo, in 20 minutes, when i started experiencing this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

There may be framework Issue change the framework to latest version. This will solved issue.